# Various methods of merging subtree not preserving commit history

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-subtree

I have two repos, `OGrepo` and `Newrepo`. `OGrepo` has two directories in it:

`OGrepo
      |-dirOne 
      |-dirTwo`

I'd like to put a *copy* of `Newrepo` inside of `dirTwo`, including every single piece of commit history that happened to `Newrepo` for its entire lifespan. I've been trying for a few hours to get this right, and have gone down some rabbit holes and now my `OGrepo` is littered with random remotes and copies of `Newrepo` at the same level as `dirOne` and `dirTwo`.

The closest I got was when I've done as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992078/7082628) answer suggests and from my terminal being pointed at the root level of `OGrepo` did the following:

`git subtree add --prefix=dirTwo/Newrepo git://github.com/theUrlOf/Newrepo master`

Then, I went `cd dirTwo` typed `git add *` and `git commit -m"message"` followed by `git push origin master`.

This does ok, all the intended files are in there and it looks good. But if I go into `dirTwo/Newrepo` there and type `git log` the only record that comes up is the the commit I just made to put it in there.

Next, I try the method laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/7082628):

```
cd path/to/OGrepo/dirTwo
git remote add Newrepo http://github.com/urlOf/NewRepo.git
git fetch Newrepo
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories Newrepo/master # this says 'already up to date when executing'
git remote remove Newrepo
```

So - after then adding * and pushing (to which it says everything is up todate). I check my github account and nothing is there.

Lastly, I have tried several different versions of this method, with this being the most concise way of stating it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1426163/7082628

And that does something similar to the first thing I've tried. Creates the directory of `Newrepo` in the right place, but the commit history is not preserved. Strangely enough, it preserves the commit history of all the other times this evening I've tried it this way, but that's it.

So, any ideas? Thanks!